# Arduino cat feeder

Tags: arduino-uno, servo, rtc

My cat feeder works like that:

1. LCD shows real time clock
2. Press a push button
3. LCD shows you to put the feeding time
4. You put the feeding time through a matricial keyboard
5. When feeding time is reached, a servo motor open the food container

The problem with my project is when the feeding time is reached, the servo motor doesn't open the food container! I'll put my code below, can you guys help me!! It's a project for college!!

```
#include  DS3231.h>
#include  Servo.h>
Servo microservo9g;
#include  LiquidCrystal.h>
#include  Keypad.h>
#include  Wire.h>

const byte ROWS = 4; // Four rows
const byte COLS = 4; // Three columns

// Define the Keymap

char hexaKeys[ROWS][COLS] = {
  {'1','2','3','A'},
  {'4','5','6','B'},
  {'7','8','9','C'},
  {'*','0','#','D'}
};

// Connect keypad ROW0, ROW1, ROW2 and ROW3 to these Arduino pins.

byte rowPins[ROWS] = {2, 3, 4, 5};

// Connect keypad COL0, COL1 and COL2 to these Arduino pins.

byte colPins[COLS] = {6, 7, 8, 9};

//  Create the Keypad
Keypad customKeypad = Keypad( makeKeymap(hexaKeys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS );
DS3231  rtc(A4, A5);
LiquidCrystal lcd(A0, A1, A2, 11, 12, 13); // Creates an LC object. Parameters: (rs, enable, d4, d5, d6, d7)
Time t;

 //int angle = 0;    
// int potentio = A0;      // initialize the A0analog pin for potentiometer
 int t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6;


boolean feed = true; // condition for alarm

 char key;
 int r[6];

 void setup()
 {
  microservo9g.attach(10);
  lcd.begin(16,2);
  microservo9g.write(0);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  rtc.begin();
  pinMode(A0, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(A1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(A2, OUTPUT);
 }

 void loop()
 {
lcd.clear();
lcd.setCursor(0,0);
int buttonPress;
buttonPress = digitalRead(A3);

if (buttonPress==1)
 setFeedingTime();
 char customKey = customKeypad.getKey();


//Serial.println(buttonPress);

 lcd.print("Time:  ");
 String t = "";
 t = rtc.getTimeStr();
 t1 = t.charAt(0)-48;
 t2 = t.charAt(1)-48;
 t3 = t.charAt(3)-48;
 t4 = t.charAt(4)-48;
 t5 = t.charAt(6)-48;
 t6 = t.charAt(7)-48;

 lcd.print(rtc.getTimeStr());
 lcd.setCursor(0,1);
 lcd.print("Date: ");
 lcd.print(rtc.getDateStr());

 if (t1==r[0] && t2==r[1] && t3==r[2] && t4==r[3]&& t5<1 && t6<3 && feed==true)
 {
  microservo9g.write(90);                  
 //command to rotate the servo to the specified angle

  delay(400);  
  microservo9g.write(0);
  feed=false;
 }
 }      

void setFeedingTime()
{
  feed = true;
   int i=0;

  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("Set feeding Time");
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("HH:MM");
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);


  while(1){

key = customKeypad.getKey();

  char j;

 if(key!=NO_KEY){

  lcd.setCursor(j,1);

  lcd.print(key);

   r[i] = key-48;
    i++;
    j++;

 if (j==2)
    {

  lcd.print(":"); j++;
    }

   delay(500);
  }

 if (key == '*')

 {key=0; break; }
  }
}
```

Comment: Align your code (select code, press ctrl-k)

Comment: Your code still looks messy with al the parenthesis not aligned (very hard to see which code belongs to an if/while statement). Did you try the servo motor in an example? Also it will help to add Serial.print statements to show exactly the values around the places where you want the motor to start (and all other relevant places), to rule out if it is a software problem or hardware problem. At least check all values for t1 to t6, r[0] to r[3] and feed.

Comment: This code would not compile: Look at the `#include` statements. Each of them is missing an  beginning  `<`.  And also your poor cat has only 400 milli sec to eat.  :-( .i.e Perhaps the door is closed before you can see it open.